# How to program small PLDs?

Tags: windows

I would like to program some small PLDs to condense glue logic in a processor design. Nothing fancy, 16L8, 22V10, that kind of thing. I don't want to fit a complete processor into a multi-thousand cell device.

Most modern windows tools want to program the latest (huge) company device offerings at the expense of the older, smaller and cheaper devices.

I have Palasm, but it is a DOS program and wants extended & expanded memory to run. I have DOS running on a modern desktop system, but it does not support what Palasm seems to want. I do not have an 80s vintage personal computer running DOS.

I have Cupl, but it does not seem to support the older, smaller devices.

I have a programmer that claims to be able to program these devices, if I can compile the source code into something it recognizes.

So, how do designers program PLD devices today?

Comment: *Way* too broad.

Comment: Please note that posters here are not just male in gender. Some of our female helpers have expressed the opinion that every time they see references to a "gentlemen" audience, they feel excluded. Therefore, please try to avoid using this sort of address, or indeed any gendered language. Thanks.